# Conditioning and Independence of probability

Tags: probability, independence, conditional-probability

Three marksmen hit the target with probabilities $ \frac{1}{2}$,$ \frac{2}{3}$ and $ {\frac{3}{4}}$ respectively.
  They shoot simultaneously and there are two hits.
Who missed? Find the probabilities.

I have tried as follows:-

$P(A~\text{hits the target})=\frac{1}{2}= P(A)$.  Similarly, $P(B)=\frac{2}{3}$ and $P(C)= \frac{3}{4}$.

Now, $P(A~\text{does not hit}) = P(A')= 1- \frac{1}{2}= \frac{1}{2}$.
  Similarly, $P(B')= \frac{1}{3}$ and $P(C')= \frac{1}{4}$.

Since all of them shoot but only two hit so we have three cases as follows:
$$P(A~\text{and}~B~\text{hit but}~C~\text{does not})=P(ABC')= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{12}$$
Similarly, 
$$P(AB'C)= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{8}$$
and 
$$P(A'BC)= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{4}$$

So, 
$$P(\text{they all shoot simultaneously but only two hit})= \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{11}{24}$$

Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
P(A~\text{missed the target}) & = \frac{P(A'BC)}{P(\text{they all shoot simultaneously but only two hit})}\\
& = \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{11}{24}}\\ 
& = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{24}{11}\\
& = \frac{6}{11}
\end{align*}

Similarly, 
$$P(B~\text{missed})=  \frac{\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{11}{24}} = \frac{3}{11}$$

$$P(C~\text{missed})= \frac{\frac{1}{12}}{\frac{11}{24}} = \frac{2}{11}$$

Please correct me wherever I am wrong, whether explanation or calculation.

Comment: Your thoughts ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Ok I will edit again.

Comment: I have added my thoughts, please help me.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B,C$ be the events that person A,B,C hit the target respectively.

Let $X$ be the event that exactly one person missed.

The probability that exactly one misses is:

$$Pr(X)=Pr((A^c\cap B\cap C)\cup (A\cap B^c\cap C)\cup (A\cap B\cap C^c))$$

Using properties of mutually exclusive events and using properties of independent events, this expands out as:

$$=Pr(A^c)Pr(B)Pr(C)+Pr(A)Pr(B^c)Pr(C)+Pr(A)Pr(B)Pr(C^c)$$

Plugging in values:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac34+\frac12\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac34+\frac12\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac14 = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{12}=\frac{11}{24}$$

We are tasked with calculating the values: $Pr(A^c\mid X)$, $Pr(B^c\mid X), Pr(C^c\mid X)$.

Remembering the definition of conditional probability: $Pr(E\mid F) = \dfrac{Pr(E\cap F)}{Pr(F)}$ we have:

$$Pr(A^c\mid X) = \frac{\frac12\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac34}{\frac{11}{24}}=\frac{6}{11}$$

Similarly calculated, we have $\frac{3}{11}$ and $\frac{2}{11}$ for the probabilities that $B$ and $C$ were the ones who missed respectively.  Your attempt was correct.